# Running commands on FreeBSD Live CD

Tags: xen, freebsd

I'm running FreeBSD 9.1-PRERELEASE on a vps running on XEN virtualization, I tried to update it to 9.1-RELEASE but mergemaster toasted my `/etc/master.passwd` and `/etc/passwd` so what i have now is a blank copies of the two files.

What i did is use a mounted Live CD and mount my root partition to `/mnt` and manually re listed every entry to `/mnt/etc/master.passwd` and `/mnt/etc/passwd` from another freebsd server. I believe that everytime you edit `master.passwd` and `passwd` you have to run `pwd_mkdb` but this gives me `"Read Only File"` error.

What I plan to do is enable PermitRootLogin and PermitEmptyPassword first so I can login as root first before I redo necessary changes again. But i have to run `pwd_mkdb`, so is there a way to run this command from Live CD?

Comment: did you check /mnt was not mounted read only?

Comment: I haven't, how do i do that anyway? I just know too little on freebsd, i can only manage it to run a webserver. Someone from another forum mention to chroot the mounted partition?

Comment: Have you tried booting the system into single user mode? Escape to the loader on boot and run 'boot -s'. If it asks for the path to SHELL, just press enter to use the default. Hopefully you should get to a command prompt. If / is mounted read-only, just run 'mount -uw /' to change the mode. You should then be able to sort out /etc/master.passwd and run 'pwd_mkdb -p /etc/master.passwd' (You may have to run 'mount -a' to mount /usr so you have the pwd_mkdb command)

Comment: @ USD Matt:
I tried that already but it hangs after i type "boot /boot/kernel.old" i think it's because i updated my OS thru "svn" and i started to do a make build world but that ssh session disconnects..

Answer (score 1):

Okay i think i got it now, after i mount `/dev/ada0p2` to `/mnt` i did a `chroot /mnt` and then i run `/usr/sbin/pwd_mkdb -p /etc/master.passwd` then restarted the server and there, i can login again using the user i manually inputted

Comment: Note: passwd and master.passwd are not used for login. pwd.db and spwd.db are used. So if they're still good, you should be able to login at least. Also, if these are overwritten by the upgrade process (mergemaster et al) a backup copy is kept in /var/backup until you reboot.